# Need to be able to recognize the email variable to complete the actor line

Tags: tin-can-api

Please have a look at my code. I'm trying to set the actor with the variables set near the top of my page. Name works fine but I can't get email to work. Can you tell me how to modify the code so that it recognizes the email variable? Right now it says 'mailto:email' and I know that is wrong and it does not work. Name does work, however, so I know that I am close. Thank you.

```
$("#myButton").click(function(){
    var name = $("#nameID").val();
    var email = $("#emailID").val();
    // Save the name in localStorage.
    localStorage.setItem('name', name);
    // Save the email in localStorage.
    localStorage.setItem('email', email);
    init();
    document.location.replace("page2.html");
});



function init() {

            var stmt = new ADL.XAPIStatement(
                new ADL.XAPIStatement.Agent('mailto:email', name),
                new ADL.XAPIStatement.Verb('http://adlnet.gov/expapi/verbs/completed', 'completed'),
                new ADL.XAPIStatement.Activity('act:http://johnmenken.blogspot.com/2016/01/practice-sending-xapi-statements.html', 'Diamond in the Rough',
                    'Article on curation by Ben Betts and Allison Anderson.')   
            );
            //generates a unique ID for the statement
            stmt.generateId();
            //Other contextual information about the Activity
            stmt.addOtherContextActivity( new ADL.XAPIStatement.Activity('Category:Curation') );
            //Registration: An instance of a learner experiencing a particular Activity.
            stmt.generateRegistration();

            ADL.XAPIWrapper.changeConfig({
                'endpoint': 'https://lrs.adlnet.gov/xapi/',
                'user': 'xapi-tools',
                'password': 'xapi-tools',
                'auth': 'xapi-tools'
            });

            ADL.XAPIWrapper.sendStatement(stmt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really so much a Tin Can API question as a plain JavaScript question.

There are any number of ways to solve this, but based on what you currently have I would either construct the Agent object in the click handler and pass it to the `init` function or pass the values for "name" and "email" to the init function themselves. Name is a red herring, it isn't likely working the way you think it is, you just happen to be getting `window.name` a global accidentally, and more than likely it is the empty string.

`init(email, name);`

And then inside of `init`:

```
function init(actorEmail, actorName) {

        var stmt = new ADL.XAPIStatement(
            new ADL.XAPIStatement.Agent('mailto:' + actorEmail, actorName),
```

I switched to include "actor" in the variable name for differentiation, but there is no technical reason why you must.